# SED does not print the last input

Tags: linux, bash, sed, stdout, tail

I'm trying to check new lines in a file using tail, then prepend each new line with something using sed, and print the output to the standard out.

The problem is, after adding a new line to the file, that line is not printed, but a previous one instead.

I am a Linux noob. So far I tried to pipe the output of sed to another program, like echo, printf, cat, more, less, but none of these worked.

I also tried adding "p" as a pattern flag at the end of the sed string, but that causes to print each string twice.

```
tail -F /usr/local/logs/myfile.log | sed -e "s/^/[hostname:$HOSTNAME] 
[file:myfile.log] /"
```

I open another terminal and enter:

```
echo "test1" >> /usr/local/logs/myfile.log
```

(nothing happens, I expected message with "test1" to be printed)

```
echo "test2" >> /usr/local/logs/myfile.log
```

(prints `[hostname:5b1dc0d27a45] [file:myfile.log] test1`, I expect "test2")

If I only use tail, without sed, each new line is displayed properly - but of course not prepended with the stuff I wanted.

Comment: What is your operation precisely, at "open another terminal and enter:"? What I actually want to ask is, what is the timeline and location of your `tail | sed` command, `echo >>` command and printed result?

Comment: It works for me (when I use `\n` instead of a newline in the sed replacement). I just need to wait for a while.

Comment: @GenoChen Hi, wha I do is: 1) use this "tail -F ...." command as the command for my docker container 2) run the container 3) open another putty session to the machine where the docker is running 4) use docker exec <container> to log into the running container 5) execute the "echo >>" commands. At this point i can still see the standard output from the container in the first window.

Comment: @choroba Can you share the sed string? I don't think I have any newline in the one that I posted.

Comment: I clearly see your sed expression has two lines, so there must be a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use tail with follow mode. So the input for sed is not closed. For optimization, output is done in blocks (buffered) or at end. `sed -u ...` should help: It changes the output mode to *unbuffered*.

Comment: That worked, thank you! For me the problem is: my sed does not have the -u flag available. Would there be any way to workaround this? I cannot update any packages in the environment that I use.

Comment: maybe: `awk '{ gsub(/.../,"..."); fflush()}'` instead of `sed`.